# Amend Regular Expression to allow German umlauts, French accents and other valid European letters

Tags: regex, angularjs

I need to validate a text input so a user can insert characters/text that may include German umlauts,  French accents and any other valid European characters, for example the minuscule ø.

I am using AngularJS so I am applying my validation rule to the `ng-pattern` attribute like so:

```
ng-pattern="/^[A-Za-z0-9 \-_.]*$/"
```

I was hoping this would cover characters like äöüß but when testing it doesn't. Sorry to ask such a lame question but I am really bad at RegEx! There must be a better way than manually listing the letters like so `ng-pattern="/^[A-Za-z0-9äöüÄÖÜ \-_.]*$/"`

Comment: Maybe you can use the external lib [XRegExp](http://xregexp.com/) with the [Unicode plugin](http://xregexp.com/plugins/), for more details, see my answers [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17358230/626273), [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7752816/626273) and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7578937/626273).

Comment: Why? Are you going to know all scripts used before? What about european languages typed in non-latin scripts?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Javascript regexes don't support unicode properties, the only way to include non-latin letters is to list them explicitly in your expression:

```
 [A-Za-z0-9 \-_.äöüß etc]
```

or use unicode ranges, e.g

```
 [A-Za-z0-9 \-_.\u00C0-\u00D6\u00D8-\u00F6\u00F8-\u00FF]
```

(see http://www.utf8-chartable.de/ for reference).

Answer (score 22):

`[a-zA-Z\x7f-\xff]` contains a lot of special characters such as ä ö ü é ß î...

Comment: Or something like `À-ž`

Comment: @celwell I was looking all over for something like that! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I faced an issue with finding a Markdown Pattern within a string but it crashed if the text contained an **umlaut** or **ß** .

Encoding the text actually helped thx to [this extension](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47940970/2500724)

No more crashes and works great.

Answer (score -3):

The following worked for me for spaces, and special characters, without numbers 
`^[a-zA-ZÀ-ž ]*$`