# Regex to prevent accented letters in the input

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, html

I want to block the entry of accented letters (any language) in input, preferably I would like this block to be done with **regex** through the attribute `pattern`

I tried something but I did not succeed...

```html
<form>
  <label for="username">Name <i>(only letters without accent)</i></label>
  <br>
  <input name="username" id="username" type="text" pattern="[A-Za-z]+" oninvalid="this.setCustomValidity('Only letters without accent')">
</form>
```

*Accepts*: `Joao Silva`, `Pedro`, `Fabio Duarte`...

*Rejects*: `João Silva`, `Pedro Camões`, `Fábio Duarte` ...

Comment: maybe a duplicate of this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30225552/regex-for-diacritics

Comment: Doesn't it reject / accept correctly if that's the current behavior?

Comment: @revo Yes, but only in the first time... If I miss the pattern and then adjust, continue firing the validation error.

Comment: Probably you want something like `pattern="[A-Z][A-Za-z]* [A-Z][A-Za-z]*"`, though it is rather restrictive (no `'` and `-` are allowed).

Comment: Your problem is with `oninvalid` attribute. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16867407/html5-why-does-my-oninvalid-attribute-let-the-pattern-fail

Comment: Also if you need spaces you should allow them in character class.

Comment: I am very curious about _**why**_ you want to prevent people from properly entering their name? My thought is that you may be trying to work around some _other_ problem that could be fixed (for example, if the database is not storing accented characters correctly the DB needs to be configured to allow it)

Comment: @StephenP Hey Stephen thanks for the advice, I remembered [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)... I'm actually doing this to avoid future problems, but if I use this, I'll use it for usernames, I used people's names only in the scope of the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<input name="username" id="username" type="text" 
    pattern="[A-Za-z ]*" title="Latin letters and space characters only"> />
```

Test this code [here](http://jsfiddle.net/19uuwj55/).

---

Alternatively, you can control what characters are allowed during typing.

```
<input name="username" id="username" type="text" onCopy="return false" 
    onDrag="return false" onDrop="return false" onPaste="return false" 
    autocomplete=off />
```

jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#username").keypress(function(event) {
        var inputValue = event.which;
        if(!((inputValue >= 65 && inputValue <=  90) ||  // A-Z
             (inputValue >= 97 && inputValue <= 122) ||  // a-z
             (inputValue == 32))) {                      // space
            event.preventDefault(); 
        }
    });
});
```

Test this code [here](http://jsfiddle.net/w9xc9hko/).

Answer (score 0):

### Original Answer

As specified in the question, it sounds like you want to block anything other than basic Latin alphabet letters and spaces, which is doable with a `pattern` attribute - the regex is `^[a-zA-Z ]+$`.

### Edit 2020-08-19

The question asks specifically about *"accented letters"*, not non-Latin-alphabet characters or non-ASCII characters. As of 2020, and [assuming you don't](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions#Browser_compatibility) need to [support Internet Explorer](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/normalize#Browser_compatibility), this is actually fairly simple to check for in JavaScript.

#### Explanation

NFD normalization splits apart all diacritics from their base characters. The regex `/\p{M}/u` matches anything in the [Unicode "Mark" category](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combining_character), such as all those diacritics we just split apart.

```js
const hasDiacritics = str =>
  /\p{M}/u.test(str.normalize('NFD'))

// tests
;[
  'Joao Silva',
  'Pedro',
  'Fabio Duarte',
  'João Silva',
  'Pedro Camões',
  'Fábio Duarte',
  'Αρσένιος',
  'Αρσενιος',
  'Александра',
  '李晓华',
].forEach(str => {
  console.log(str, hasDiacritics(str))
})
```

You could use a similar method to strip diacritics:

```js
const stripDiacritics = str =>
  str.normalize('NFD').replace(/\p{M}+/gu, '')


stripDiacritics('ZA̡͊͠͝LGΌ ISͮ̂҉̯͈͕̹̘̱ TO͇̹̺ͅƝ̴ȳ̳ TH̘Ë͖́̉ ͠P̯͍̭O̚​N̐Y̡ H̸̡̪̯ͨ͊̽̅̾̎Ȩ̬̩̾͛ͪ̈́̀́͘ ̶̧̨̱̹̭̯ͧ̾ͬC̷̙̲̝͖ͭ̏ͥͮ͟Oͮ͏̮̪̝͍M̲̖͊̒ͪͩͬ̚̚͜Ȇ̴̟̟͙̞ͩ͌͝S̨̥̫͎̭ͯ̿̔̀ͅ')


// => "ZALGΟ IS TOƝy THE PO​NY HE COMES"
```

### Caveats

As pointed out in [the article](https://www.kalzumeus.com/2010/06/17/falsehoods-programmers-believe-about-names/) @Stephen P links to in the comment below, **this is probably a bad idea**. It's worth thinking carefully about whether you want to risk annoying or even offending your users by forcing them to enter something that isn't their real name.

Comment: I am _completely_ on-board with what you are saying, and I often cite [Falsehoods Programmers Believe About Names](https://www.kalzumeus.com/2010/06/17/falsehoods-programmers-believe-about-names/) ... but this may have been better as a _comment_ on the question.

Comment: @StephenP That's possibly true. I'm new to SO, so I'm not exactly sure what the protocol is where you have a comment that contains an answer. I've rephrased it to give more prominence to the answer part and also tailor the answer to fit the question better.

Comment: I think your edit was the perfect way to handle this.